# Gps tracking in android

Tags: android, gps

I'm trying to write application that track my gps coordinates. 
Every 10 seconds i want to send my coordinates to server - for this i using AlarmManager.
For getting coordinates i'm using Service that implement onClickListener.
How i start service:

```
 public void startAlarm() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GpsService.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0,
            10 * 1000, pintent);
}
```

My gps service:

```
public class GpsService extends Service implements LocationListener {
// Declaring a Location Manager
private LocationManager locationManager;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude
double accuracy;
// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 10 * 1; //10secs

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if(locationManager == null ) {
    locationManager = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
    }
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    getLocation();
    if (location != null) {
        //send to server
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    locationManager = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.v("myLogs", "GetLocation service: ONLOCATIONCHANGED");
    this.location = location;
}
public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (!isGPSEnabled ) {
            stopSelf();
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return location;
}
```

}

It work perfect on emulator, but on real device it only show GPS Finding icon. What is problem?

Comment: Depending on your last GPS-fix (time and location), on your location and environmental factors it may take several minutes to get a GPS-fix.

Comment: Here's the url of my GPS class: https://github.com/techartist/GPSDistanceTracking/blob/master/src/com/webnation/gpsdistancetrackingemail/GPSTracker.java